# Sticky Tortilla Dough, when to knead, when to rest and when to add flour?

Tags: bread, tortilla

I am relatively new to baking and today I attempted to make flour tortillas. I tried making this recipe with butter: https://www.kingarthurbaking.com/recipes/simple-tortillas-recipe

I found my dough to be very sticky so I kept kneading, adding flour and resting in hopes it would fix itself. It feels like I am flying blind in how to "fix" the dough when it comes to deciding should I knead more, should I add flour, should I let it rest does anyone have any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do any of the three; there is nothing to fix. This dough is supposed to be sticky. If you do anything to "fix" the stickiness, the texture of the baked tortillas will be wrong.

Some resting is good, but it's more about improving hydration than about reducing stickiness; you should have shortened the dough anyway (step 2 in your recipe) so you won't get much gluten formation from the resting. The overnight rest they mention is also meant to give you more flexibility in your time schedule, not for reasons related to texture.

In the end, it's a sticky short dough, and you have to roll it out as such. Roll it on flour, and with some practice, you'll get the knack of handling it.